# "WebSocket opening handshake timed out" when i try to connect to direcline.botframework.com in my chrome browser (MacOS)

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I'm seeing below error when i try to connect to direcline.botframework.com in chrome browser from MacBook, but i'm able to successfully connect from other Mac machine with same configuration. I'm checked the keychain setting between 2 machine and it looks same. I'm not sure what i'm missing here.

*wss://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/<>/stream?watermark=-&t=<>' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out
(anonymous)*

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: Yes issue is resolved this behaviour is due to individual network problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to network problem for an individual user, this has been fixed by connecting site via correct VPN.